# Presentation of subgroup

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be the group with presentation
$$G = \langle \sigma_1 ,\sigma _2 , \sigma _3\, |\, \sigma _1^2=\sigma _2^2=\sigma _3^2=(\sigma _1\sigma _2)^p =(\sigma _2\sigma _3)^q =(\sigma _3\sigma _1)^r =1\rangle .$$
I want to have a presentation for the subgroup $H$ generated by the elements $\tau _1=\sigma _1\sigma _2,\, \tau _2=\sigma _2\sigma _3,\ \tau _3=\sigma _3\sigma _1$.

Is it enough to conjecture the presentation
$$ H=\langle \tau _1,\tau _2 ,\tau _3\, |\, \tau _1^p=\tau _2^q=\tau _3^r=\tau _1\tau _2\tau _3 =1 \rangle$$
and argue that the relations in the presentation of $G$ clearly imply the ones conjectured for $H$ and that the relations of $H$ imply the relations in the presentation of $G$.

Comment: The group is a [triangle group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group). I don't know whether this helps or not though.

Comment: No, this is not sufficient, as there may be "hidden" relations. Either you need to do more work (expand on your word "clearly"), or you can use Reidemeister-Schreier (Google it, or search this site), which gives a process to find a presentation of a given subgroup of a group. It works nicely here because $H$ has finite index in $G$.

Comment: But in fact the conjectured presentation of $H$ is correct - you just need to prove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked up the Reidemeister-Schreier method and got the presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not sufficient, as there may be "hidden" relations. In your example, $H$ does indeed have the given presentation, and it is presumably possible to show this "by hand" using properties of the group $G$, but it is not "clearly" true.

Alternatively, you can use the Reidemeister-Schreier method. This is a process to find a presentation of a given subgroup of a group, and it works nicely here because $H$ has finite index in $G$. There are two approaches to the method: the classical combinatorial/algebraic version as covered in Section 2.3 of the book *Combinatorial group theory* by Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, or in Section II.4 of Lyndon and Schupp's book of the same name, and the topological version using coverings of presentation complexes (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398375/10513)). Personally, I favour the topological version, as I view it as a "visualisation" of the algebraic version.

The process can also be done on a computer (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746916/10513)), although the computer will want $p,q,r$ to be fixed.